# R fitting a polynomial on data

Tags: r, linear-regression, polynomial-math, lm

I have some data synthetically generated from a function which is shown below.

```
fn <- function(w1,w2){
  f= -(0.1 + 1.3*w1 + 0.4*w2 - 1.8*w1*w1 - 1.8*w2*w2)
  return(f)
}
```

Next I create a data frame with the values as shown below

```
x = data.frame(
  yval = fn(seq(0.1,0.9,by=0.01),seq(1.1,0.3,by=-0.01)),
  x1 = seq(0.1,0.9,by=0.01),
  x2 = seq(1.1,0.3,by=-0.01)
)
```

I want to see if I can recreate the coefficients of the polynomial in fn by using a polynomial fit which I attempt as shown below

```
fit = lm(yval ~ x1 + x2 + I(x1^2) + I(x2^2),data=x)
coef(fit)
```

However when I run the above code, I get the following

```
(Intercept)          x1          x2     I(x1^2)     I(x2^2) 
      2.012      -5.220          NA       3.600          NA
```

It appears that the term x2 was never "detected". Would anybody know what I could be doing wrong? I know that if I create synthetic linear data and try to re-create the coefficients using lm, I would get back the coefficients fairly accurately. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `x1` and `x2` are perfectly collinear, thus parameters can't be estimated for both simultaneously.  R recognizes this and sets one of them to `NA`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're fitting to a grid of 2 predictors, you want `expand.grid`.

```
x <- expand.grid(x1=seq(0.1, 0.9, by=0.01), x2=seq(1.1, 0.3, by=-0.01))
x$yval <- with(x, fn(x1, x2))

fit = lm(yval ~ x1 + x2 + I(x1^2) + I(x2^2),data=x)
coef(fit)
(Intercept)          x1          x2     I(x1^2)     I(x2^2) 
       -0.1        -1.3        -0.4         1.8         1.8
```